# Django Login bizare behavior

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to build a web app. I have built both the login and the registration on the home page as I'd like them to be right there, and I have a problem with the login.

If I enter the correct credentials, it logs me in without any problem, but if I enter wrong credentials I get no error whatsoever, it just tells me that my view returned none.

Here's my Views Code:

```
class MainView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        return HttpResponse(
            "Welcome " + user.username + ", You are Logged in!! you can logout <a href=/logout/>here</a>")


class HomeView(View):
    form_class_reg = SignUpForm
    form_class_login = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'main/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated is True:
            return MainView.as_view()(self.request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated is False:
            form_reg = self.form_class_reg(prefix='SignUpForm')
            form_login = self.form_class_login(prefix='SignInForm')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {
                'form_reg': form_reg,
                'form_login': form_login, })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_reg = self.form_class_reg(request.POST, prefix='SignUpForm')
        form_login = self.form_class_login(data=request.POST, prefix='SignInForm')
        if form_reg.is_valid():
            form_reg.save()
            username = form_reg.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form_reg.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        if form_login.is_valid():
            username = form_login.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form_login.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong credentials")
```

So if user credentials are correct it redirects me to / which is HomeView and then to MainView as it is my login page that I will build later, but if I enter wrong username/pass, it never gives me the wrong credentials return.

It just gives me this:

```
The view main.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Any Idea?

Comment: If you get `view returned none`, that means you never end up in a branch that would return anything else, so neither form is valid. You can try `print(form_reg.errors)` (and likewise for `form_login`) within the `post()` method to see what the error(s) are that make that happen.

Comment: In order for the form to be valid that means that id and password must be correct or just the requirements are met?

Comment: @KuriakosLukoudis it depends on your form implementation, cannot answer that without the form's code. If you just defined fields and did not write any code checking for user credentials in the form, then it should just do basic field validation.

Comment: For `AuthenticationForm`, the username and password must be correct, yes. https://github.com/django/django/blob/392963e8e4605ff6da770450623ceaef0892cab7/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L189-L200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is `None` then the code isn't entering the body of the conditional `if form_reg.is_valid():` and since the `else` case isn't handled the function returns `None`. You should check `form.errors` to check why your form validation isn't working like you expect.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, the validation ment it check for credentials so if they were wrong i didnt got any returns!